# watir on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, watir, watir-webdriver

I've just updated my system from ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10 and...surprise!
Now if I try to use watir, doing

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
```

I obtain this error

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/json_pure-1.6.1.gemspec]: 
      invalid date format in specification: "2011-09-18 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/watir-webdriver-0.3.5.gemspec]: 
      invalid date format in specification: "2011-10-05 00:00:00.000000000Z"

LoadError: no such file to load -- watir-webdriver
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from (irb):3
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb:22
```

How to make it work again?

Answer (score 1):

All I know about running Watir on Linux is here:

https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook/blob/master/installation/ubuntu.md

Did you check if Ubuntu update broke your Ruby installation? Maybe it uninstalled watir-webdriver gem or something.

What do you get for `gem list watir`?

Comment: I followed that guide too..I also try a fresh installation (yes, I had to format my pc) but the result still the same

Comment: I will try to install Watir on Ubuntu 11.10 this weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Your version of ruby has problems. Install RVM, and get it to install a fresh ruby:

```
 1. bash < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )
 2. echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
 3. source .bash_profile 
 4. rvm install 1.9.2
 5. rvm use 1.9.2
```

Comment: I formatted my pc and I installed ruby from scratch follwing the guide suggested by Željko Filipin in the other answer...still same errors...

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and could fix it by adjusting the jason spec file:
/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/json_pure-1.6.1.gemspec

In the date format line I removed everything which looked like this "00:00:00.000000000Z"
and kept just the plain date format.

After again installing watir (see watir installation web page)
everything worked properly:

sudo apt-get install rubygems
gem install watir --no-rdoc --no-ri

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue with the json gem (and now that I've upgraded to 11.10 other gems).  The fix I'd previously seen for the json gem was to go into the gem file and listed in the error and remove the "00:00:00.000000000Z" string wherever you found it.

I've used it on every gem I've received this error on (which was only a couple but I don't remember which exactly).  The the gems seem to work just fine.  I haven't noticed any problems since removing that string.